# Getting MySQL error creating handler in an event

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I'm trying to create an Event in MySQL 5.6 and I'm getting an error whenever I try to DECLARE something, like a parameter or handler:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION            SET @rollMeBack = TRUE;

I'm a SQL Server guy and the syntax is giving me ulcers. I tried declaring a variable like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599773/mysql-event-scheduler-using-local-variable), but I still get the error at that line. Help me Obi Wan Kenobi: you're my only hope.

Entire (obfuscated) code:

```
DELIMITER ||

CREATE EVENT my_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT 'Fixes status'
DO IF EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL FROM [...problem records..]
    ) THEN
        -- =================================================================================================
        -- Get a complete list of bad records:
    SET @rollMeBack = FALSE ;

        SET @LogId = 0;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE updateable
            SELECT DISTINCT e.id , (@LogId:=@LogId + 1) + (SELECT MAX(dsd.id) FROM LogTable dsd ) AS LogId
            FROM Table1 e 
                INNER JOIN Table2 r
                    ON r.e_id = e.id 
                    /*Waiting 5 minutes to not interfere with current operations:*/
                    AND r.rDateTime <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
            WHERE e.Status = 'Sent'
                AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Table2 r2 WHERE r2.e_id = e.id and r2.rDateTime is null)
            LIMIT 100 ;
        
        -- =================================================================================================
        -- =================================================================================================
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
            SET @rollMeBack = TRUE;

        START TRANSACTION
            -- =================================================================================================
            UPDATE Table1 as e1 
                INNER JOIN updateable AS u
                    ON e1.d=id = u.id
            SET e1.Status = 'Completed',
                e1.cDateTime = COALESCE (e1.cDateTime, (select max(rDateTime) from Table2 r5 where r5.e_id = e1.id));
            -- =================================================================================================
            -- Log updates:
            INSERT INTO Debug (ID, Message)
            SELECT u.LogId,
                'Record set to `Completed`'
            FROM updateable AS u;
            -- =================================================================================================
            -- Cleanup:
            DROP TABLE updateable;

        IF @rollMeBack = TRUE THEN
            ROLLBACK;
        ELSE
            COMMIT;
        END IF
        -- =================================================================================================
        -- =================================================================================================
    END IF; ||
```

DELIMITER ;

Comment: Any chance of showing the code that is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of modifications render this operable.

Firstly, the handler must be declared in the correct place.  From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html):

> Handler declarations must appear after variable or condition
> declarations.

Secondly, the `DO IF EXISTS...END IF;` should contain a `BEGIN...END` block after which you do your handler declaration:

```
...
COMMENT 'Fixes status'
DO IF EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL FROM [...problem records..]
    ) THEN
    BEGIN -- Note the added begin
        -- Moved the handler declaration to be the first statement of this block
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
            SET @rollMeBack = TRUE;

        -- =================================================================================================
        -- Get a complete list of bad records:
    SET @rollMeBack = FALSE ;
    ...
```

At the end of the code:

```
        ...
        -- =================================================================================================
    END; -- Note the added END
END IF; ||

DELIMITER ;
```

Incidentally, there is also a syntax error in the `IF @rollMeBack = TRUE THEN...END IF` block - the semi-colon is missing from the end of `END IF`.